# Почему улетел календарь?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Есть такая [страница](http://idriska-tour.com/hotels/castilla-alicante/) сайта, на которой раньше в сайдбаре нормально работал bootstrap datepicker, после того как было переделано сайдбар со статичного в "прилипающий", начались проблемы с тем же календарем, а именно он работает, но появляется в самом верху на слайдере, что не есть ок.

Comment: Скажите, а где должен появляться календарь?

Comment: Под маленьким календариком в сайдбаре

Answer (score 0):

Вместо кода

```js
var n_left = f_getPosition (this, 'Left'),
    n_top  = f_getPosition (this, 'Top') + this.offsetHeight;
```

установил подобранные константы

```js
var n_left = x,
    n_top  = y;
```

и сделал, что бы календарь прикреплялся не к body, а div`у со свойством position: relative; внутри section самого сайдбара

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("sticky_temp_wrap").item(0).appendChild(e_cal);
```

в принципе календарь появляется не под каждым инпутом как раньше, а оба в 1 месте, но это не проблема я думаю, главное что ни где попало и проблема решена.
Подробней на тостере: https://toster.ru/q/434434